# Condemnable limit for the electrostatic field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

When we define the electrostatic field (law's Coulomb), generated by a $Q$ charge calculated in a point $P$ of the space, we place a particle with a small positive charge $q_0$, called a *test charge* because we use it to test the field.

$$\mathbf{E} =\frac{\mathbf{F}_{C}}{q_0}$$

The charge to be small so that it does not disturb the object's charge distribution. In this case it is only $Q$.

I have read on some Italian notes this:

The test charge $q_0$ in turn, exerts on a discrete distribution of charges
$q_i$ (or on $Q$), reaction forces that can change position
sources: as is often the case in Physics, the instrument
The measured value can alter the measured value. Obviously,
in a well-conducted experiment, it should be borne in mind that
this effect, choosing $q_0$ small enough to produce
a negligible disturbance of the field, and where this
it is not possible to take them into account by means of an appropriate
analysis, which will be based, in any case, on the definition of
electric field given to the side. The habit of many authors of
to write
$$\mathbf{E} =\lim_{q_0\to 0}\frac{\mathbf{F}_{C}}{q_0}$$

is condemnable for misuse
of the mathematical symbol
of limit, misleading, because
it's not true that the disturbance
produced by the charge of
evidence can always be rendered
negligible, and above all, is
because the definition of
applies without any
restriction on charging $q_0$.

Is it correct this observation of an italian author of some your notes?

Comment: You can say that you fix the source charges so that they cannot be displaced by the test charge. Then it does not depend on the magnitude of the test charge.

Comment: The limit makes sense to me, provided we understand that $\mathbf{F}_C$ is a function of $q_0$. Is there something else I'm missing as to why the limit is inappropriate?

Comment: @LedHead Now I edit my question and put the italian notes.

Comment: I don’t see anything “condemnable”. Experimental difficulties have nothing to do with conceptual definitions.

Comment: @G.Smith Therefore what are the exact conclusions?

Comment: @LedHead A detailed answer is always welcome.

Comment: My own conclusions are: 1. If one insists on defining electric field via electric force, then I don’t see a conceptual problem with imagining an infinitesimal test charge. 2. I would prefer to define electric and magnetic fields via Maxwell’s equations, and their effects through the Lorentz force law, and never mention “test charges” at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because has solved with severals comment.

Comment: There isn't a question here; I'm voting to close as Unclear What You're Asking, but I'm happy to retract/VTR if this gets fixed. (As far as this question getting closed, though - are you sure that's what you want? It will definitely make [this problem](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11410) worse. Why not fix the question instead, and, if you've already understood, answer it yourself?)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Hi, I have thought that anything I have read in university or school books was improperly written. The G. Smith's answer in the comment first point, he made me understand that the concept of condemnable limit is due only to a critical thought of the author of the notes in Italian.